# Spring data cassandra repository custom query fired status

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring boot repository for CRUD operation in `Cassandra`.

**MyPointsRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface MyPointsRepository extends CassandraRepository<MyPoints> {

    @Query("update my_points set points = points + ?2 where app_id=?0 and user_name=?1")
    public void incrementMyPoints(long appId, String userName, int points);
}
```

I am **successfully** able to perform **CRUD** operation in Cassandra using the above repository.

What I want to achieve is:
Instead of returning `void`, I want to return the status of the query, kind of `ResultSet`, so that I can know the status of the query, whether it is saved or not.

How can I achieve this in spring data repository?

Comment: What do you mean by it's saved or not?

Comment: If I use `Cassandra template `  to save data in database then I receive `ResultSetFuture` as a response which contains information such as if data is successfully saved in database or not. If there is some problem while saving data as an example `Timeout Exception`, then this result set contains the information about the success/failure of query

Comment: Two things: The future isn’t passed to the repository implementation. Synchronisation happens inside the implementation and the appropriate exception is thrown upon error. Void doesn’t mean fire and forget but just no result value.

Comment: I just stopped my Cassandra server explicitly and I received `NoHostAvailable` exception, which is an expected behaviour. I want to know will I get any error in case of `Timeout`,  in case of `minimum replication factor` not met, etc etc when using repository. Also, is repository is a sync or asynchronous task.